# How to export hive query result to single local file?

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hiveql, reduce, hive-configuration

I want to export hive query result to single local file with pipe delimiter.

**Hive query contains order by clause.**

I have tried below solutions.

**Solution1:**

```
hive -e 'insert overwrite local directory '/problem1/solution' fields terminated by '|' select * from table_name order by rec_date'
```

This solution is creating multiple files. After merging files, it loosing data order.

**Solution2:**

```
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://server_ip:10000/db_name' --silent --outputformat=dsv --delimiterForDSV='|' -e 'select * from table_name order by rec_date' > /problem1/solution
```

This solution is creating single file but it has empty 2 lines at top and 2 lines at bottom.

I am removing empty lines using **sed** command. It takes very long time.

Is there any other efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these settings for executing ORDER BY on single reducer:

```
set hive.optimize.sampling.orderby=false; --disable parallel ORDER BY
```

Or try to set the number of reducers manually:

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks=1;
```